# WmiPrvSE.exe on Firefox Start-up

Tags: firefox

Since updating to FF 32.0.2, 'WmiPrvSE.exe' starts automatically on Firefox start-up.
Any idea how to fix it?

Win 7, 32-bit.

Thank you.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1070123

Comment: Um, so FireFox makes a WMI call. The fix would obviously be to re-compile Firefox after omitting the code that makes that (or those) WMI calls. Really though, what is the *problem*? Is it consuming resources at an alarming rate?

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Start-up is a bit slower. But mainly - I think it's an indication to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only "problem" here is understanding what WMI and WMIPrvSE.exe is.

WMI is **Windows Management Instrumentation**

~From Wikipedia:

> Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is a set of extensions to the
>   Windows Driver Model that provides an operating system interface
>   through which instrumented components provide information and
>   notification. WMI is Microsoft's implementation of the Web-Based
>   Enterprise Management (WBEM) and Common Information Model (CIM)
>   standards from the Distributed Management Task Force (DMTF).
>
> WMI allows scripting languages like VBScript or Windows PowerShell to
>   manage Microsoft Windows personal computers and servers, both locally
>   and remotely. WMI is preinstalled in Windows 2000 and newer OSs. It is
>   available as a download for Windows NT,[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcCvD.png) Windows 95 and Windows
>   98.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo7EB.png)

WMI is essential in some applications, and each time a new WMI process is started you will see a new instance of WmiPRVSE.exe in your processes.

To illustrate this, open a command window and run the command:

```
wmic process get name
```

You will see where wmic.exe and also wmiPrvSE.exe are running, if you hit the up arrow and run it again you will see the same results:

[image]

Now, open a second command line and enter the following:

```
wmic /?
```

You will notice you are sort of stuck in a mode to enter your class/ namespace. Now go back to the first command windows, leaving this one open and run that same command again. You will see you now have two instances of WMIPrvSE.exe running.

[image]

Having these running is really in no way a problem. WMI is often not the best way to get information, but it is generally an easy way to get information. For example I can get environment data like username `wmic environment get username` to find out the username... Or in the case of something like Firefox that can be installed portable, I can find out where the application is actually running from to load or update configuration files/ bookmarks etc:

```
wmic process get executablePath
```

---

In short, as far as fixing the problem:

Firefox would need to replace whatever WMI is doing with something else, likely at the risk of losing forward compatibility (Let Microsoft worry about getting this variable for us in Windows 14!).

It should not cause or be the sign of a problem, assuming the application is actually WMIPRVSE.exe and not a virus running from say ~\appdata\~

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it.

Some Win 7-Firefox 32 users reported that the process does not start with FF.

Up until a couple of days ago, it wouldn't start on my system either.

It's not a major issue, but I'd like to know what has caused the change.

Comment: You stated it happened with a new release, I suspect something new in the codebase... But I can't prove or confirm that. WMI in applications is not entirely uncommon.